# Show $f(t) = t$ given $\int_0^1 t^n f(t) dt = \frac{1}{n+2}\quad \forall n\in\mathbb{N}.$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f$ be in $L^2(0,1)$, show that $f(t) = t$ if and only if 
$$\int_0^1 t^n f(t) dt = \frac{1}{n+2}\quad \forall n\in\mathbb{N}.$$

To show $\Leftarrow$

Let $g(t) = f(t) - t$, then 
$$\int_0^1 t^n g(t) dt= \int_0^1 t^n (f(t) - t)dt = \int_0^1 t^n f(t) dt  - \int_0^1 t^{n+1} dt = \frac{1}{n+2}-\frac{1}{n+2}=0. $$

Since the Legendre polynomial forms a orthonormal basis for $L^2(0,1)$, we have
$\langle g, P_m\rangle=0$ for all $P_m$, thus $g \equiv 0$.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @DennisGulko it is a proof-verification. I am working on some of the previous exam questions.

Comment: Then - it seems correct!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\{1, t, t^2, \cdots, t^n, \cdots\}$ is dense in $L^2(0,1)$.